# jQuery UI AutoComplete Not Showing Suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following code to dynamically create an INPUT element and assign auto complete features to it. There is some problem with the .autocomplete line because the next line which adds the element to td never gets executed.

```
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];

var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input/>");

$(fileCodeAutoComplete).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
}); 

$(td).append(fileCodeAutoComplete);
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I placed a try-catch around the autocomplete call and found the error to be:

"object does not support this property or method".

This is weird because I have added the jquery-ui reference to the page.

**UPDATE 2:**

I updated the code to follows and still receive the "object does not support this property or method".

```
var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input/>");
    $(fileCodeAutoComplete).attr("id", "fileCodeAutoComplete"); 

    try {
        $("input#fileCodeAutoComplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    }
    catch(ex) {
        alert(ex.message); 
    }

    $(td).append(fileCodeAutoComplete);
```

**UPDATE 3:** I made a new project and copy pasted the code and it worked but on the existing project it does not seems to be working. I think it might be the Microsoft Library is getting in the way.

**UPDATE 4: SOLUTION**

The problem was that someone else was referring to an older version of jQuery which was messing with the jQuery UI framework.

Comment: If you put the `$(td).append()` before the `$(fileCodeAutoComplete).autocomplete()`, does it work?

Comment: It does add the TextBox to the td but without any autocomplete feature.

Comment: Does it attach the autocomplete behavior to any of the inputs? I would expect you'd need to loop through your inputs to attach the behavior to more than one (using .each for example)

Comment: I am just attaching to one textbox as shown in the code above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input/>");
```

try giving in a selector rahter than  a tag, like for example

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
```

then you give

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
```

you can refer the [link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete)

Comment: this looks correct as not having an ID would make it hard for the browser to find the element to assign an event handler in the first place

Comment: if you want to use it for every input in the page, use input selector in jquery like jQuery(":input")

Comment: why do you want to set the id using jquery, can't you set it in your html, if you cant try jquery input selector something like jQuery(":input") where it selects all the inputs in the page and creates an autocomplete on them.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding attributes to the input tag? something like:

```
var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input type='text' />");
```

Also, how about trying the autocomplete on a known input element to see if the autocomplete functionality is breaking it, or if it's the dynamic input field you're adding the functionality to?

Comment: Just tried it! With the autocomplete call it does not even create the TextBoxes. If I remove that call it does create the TextBox.

Comment: The default type for an `<input/>` is  `text` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes the default is text that is why I was not including it.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare:

```
var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input/>");
```

It's already a jquery object, you don't have to wrap it in $() again.  you can also chain the creation of the input and the autocomplete:

```
var fileCodeAutoComplete = $("<input/>")
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    })
    .appendTo(td);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/L8yvb/

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bH9ab/1/

I used your original code nearly verbatim (other than mocking a table cell to append the input).

To validate that the reference to jQuery UI is correct (and that it isn't corrupt, truncated, etc. on your local machine), you can point to Google's CDN:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Not sure! Maybe some other libraries are messing with it

Comment: @azamsharp - are you sure the reference to jQuery UI is correct? I know you said you had it directly on the page, but have you validated that the URL is working?

Comment: @TimMedora Actually the jQuery UI library is in my scripts folder and yes it is getting rendered.

Comment: @azamsharp - I'm assuming that you aren't seeing any other script errors on your page and that your markup validates...apart from that, perhaps you should create another plain HTML page in your development environment and only copy the relevant pieces from the broken page and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Populus - that's a redundant selector (unneeded qualification) and you can certainly attach events to anonymous elements using jQuery (which assigns its own ID to each managed element internally). Both fiddles posted show that the OP's code is correct without having to use a specific selector.